# "Functions are not valid as a React child." No permite la redirección a otras páginas

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

estoy iniciando en el uso de React y tengo el siguiente caso:
Cree una barra de navegación de la siguiente manera:

**Sidebar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../assests/logo-transp.png";
import "../index.css";
import { BsBookHalf,BsReceipt } from "react-icons/bs";
import { FaQuestionCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function SideBar() {
  return (
    <div className="sideBar">
      <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="logo-sidebar" />
      <div className="wrapper-icons">
        <ul>
          <li>
          <Link to='/inventario' className="a"><BsBookHalf/></Link>
          </li>

          <li>
          <Link to='/ventas' className="a"><BsReceipt/></Link>
          </li>

          <li>
          <Link to='/faq' className="a"><FaQuestionCircle/></Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default SideBar;
```

En App.js utilizo Router para poder redirigir a otras páginas mediante la barra de navegación:

```
import "./index.css";
import SideBar from "./components/SideBar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Inventario from "./pages/Inventario";
import Ventas from "./pages/Ventas";
import FAQ from "./pages/FAQ";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <SideBar />
        <div className="main">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/inventario" exact={true} element={Inventario} />

            <Route  path="/ventas" exact={true} element={Ventas} />

            <Route  path="/faq" exact={true} element={FAQ} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Pero al momento de ver la consola, me da el error de

**Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97274:5)
at div
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97207:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:96683:5)
at App**

Y por supuesto no hace nada al momento de dar click en las opciones. Además al momento de poner de manera manual el path en la barra del navegador, no se muestra lo que se encuentra en las páginas que corresponden. Estoy usando la versión 6.2.2 de react-router-dom.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Intenta pasarlos asi `element={<Inventario />}`

Comment: @g.4 Muchas gracias! Ya funciona